# dq transformation using phasor quantities

Tags: ac, phasor

3 phase AC quantities can be either represented in the Time domain or the phasor domain. It is also possible to transform 3 phase quantity to alpha-beta or d-q-0 reference frame using Clarke's transform and Parks's transform respectively. Usually, the transformation is done on AC quantities in the time domain. My question is whether Park's transform can be applied on AC quantities in the phasor domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Park-vector \${\over i (t)}\$ represents the magnetomotive force of the three-phase winding system denoted by  \$\alpha \beta \$ or d, q instead of x, y.

For 3 phase currents a,b,c including the 120 angle , a denotes the real axis.

[image]

Park transforms can also be done by Fourier Sereis for steady state.

[Ref](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLncC505zaAhXB6CwKHXyJBP4QFggoMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2FS1474667017666345%2Fpdf%3Fmd5%3De2cc84b71912792d89b492f8ba272013%26pid%3D1-s2.0-S1474667017666345-main.pdf&usg=AOvVaw13KgLeFu6o6RMoTJNo_QRt)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just to clarify are you saying that Park's transform can only be applied to a phasor domain AC quantity if it is in steady state i.e. magnitude, frequency, and phase remaining constant.

Comment: No, Startup  differs , and Fourier method can be done